# Display alert after form is submitted and page has refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to display a alert once my form has been submitted and the page has been reloaded.

Currently i have

```
$('#Form_Form_action_submit').click(function(){
 alert('Please wait while form is submitting');
 $('#Form_Form').submit();
});
```

where `Form_Form_action_submit` is the submit button id and `Form_Form` is the form id. This is only working as soon as you click submit rather than after the page loading.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make the form send the user to another page, which then pops up the alert?

Comment: ideally it would display on the same page

Comment: why don't you use ajax?

Comment: it is not user friendly to make user wait like @NaN suggested its better to use ajax.

Comment: is there somewhere i can go that will give me the ajax for this? thanks

Comment: if you want to learn how to use ajax with forms I'd recommend [jQuery's tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ajax-and-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alert after refreshing the page, then you need to send something to the next page (or the page refreshed). In this case, maybe a GET variable could be good "?submitted=true".

The only thing you need to do is to detect if there is a submitted GET variable:

```js
if (getUrlVars()["submitted"] == true) {
  alert('My alert');
}

function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
```